# Getting xsl value-of href attribute of a link tag which has a specific rel when there are multiple link tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file which has multiple tags named tag1 and each entry tags has mulitple link tags, I need the href of the link tag, whose rel="x"

```
   <tag1>
      <id>1</id>
      <timestamp>2023-04-03T07:36:54.100Z</timestamp>
      <updated>2023-04-03T07:36:54.100Z</updated>
      <link href="https://the-link-i-need" rel="x-icon" />
      <link href="https://another-link" rel="y" />
   </tag1>
```

I tried this ,but it gives me all the links of all the "tag1" tags, and iconLink gives just the first href from first link tag of first tag1 everytime.

```
<xsl:for-each select="tag1">
                        <div >                            
                                <xsl:for-each select="//link[contains(@rel, 'icon')]">
                                    <p>
                                        Link: <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
                                    </p>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//link[contains(@rel, 'icon')]/@href"/>

                                <xsl:variable name="iconLink" select="//link[contains(@rel,'icon')]/@href" />
                                <div>
                                    <xsl:if test="$iconLink">
                                        <img src="{$iconLink}" alt="icon" />
                                    </xsl:if>

                                </div>                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer `<xsl:for-each select="tag1">` changes the context node to be a `tag1` element, any paths used inside should be relative to that element so to select the `link` children don't use `//link` but simply `link`.

Comment: thanks, I get what i need using <xsl:value-of select="link[contains(@rel, 'icon')]/@href"/>, but get number format exception when using the same as a variable iconLink ,which i need to use the value in img tag

Comment: @ShrutiBansal, that seems to be a different issue, raise that as a different question.